# .htaccess rewrite_rule not working on web server, but yes locally

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

First of all, yes, I did look for and read every question related to this and I didn't seem to find any solution to my problem.

I have a simple url shortener with an htaccess that picks up an id and redirects from a basic `mypage.php/id` to `mypage.php?redirect=id`

Now, the problem is it works fine locally (MAMP) but I uploaded it a few hours ago to an online web server to test it out and it does not work. It shows a 404 page with the message `Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at mysite Port 80`.

I have tried typing the full `mypage.php?redirect=id` url and it works fine so there's no sql errors whatsoever. The rest of the site works fine too.
The only thing I see different is the Apache version, but I don't know how to do a fix around that. My version locally is Apache/2.2.23.

I'm going into my 3rd hour of research and I can't make it work I think I might be going crazy right now.

Here's my .htacces file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

#Convert
RewriteRule ^([\w\d]{4})$ mypage.php?redirect=$1 [L]
```

Could anyone be please be so kind to tell me what to do? Id be really grateful.

Thank you!

Comment: "3rd hour" lol. Make sure the .htaccess file exists. Make sure `Override ALL` is present in the apache conf under `<Directory>`. Make sure all the files have the right permissions. Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled on the server.

Comment: Lol yeah, the htaccess exists. But im gonna give the `Override ALL` a try. How can i open apache.conf in my web server? Never done it on an actual hosting server, always locally (Im a designer moving onto coding :) ) Thanks @castis !

Comment: Did you send the .htaccess file in text mode with your ftp program ?